# Only if ~ is~ : inversion?

Tags: grammar, inversion

Sentence: Only if we go out there and clean it up this amount of plastic is going to go down.

Is this grammatically correct? I heard that when "Only if" is used, we invert the subject and auxiliary.
So will it be?: Only if we go out there and clean it up is this amount of plastic going to go down.

---

Here is a link to a video clip of the sentence (around 37-38 seconds into the clip): [Could this giant floating pipe clean up 90% of ocean plastic? (CNN)](https://www.cnn.com/videos/business/2018/10/12/ocean-cleanup-plastic-mission-ahead-orig.cnn-business/video/playlists/project-planet/)

Comment: Yes, "only" triggers subject-auxiliary inversion, as in your second example.

Comment: Is that all you want to know?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the response. I found this sentence on a textbook. However it was a dialogue, so maybe the speaker didn't have enough time to think about it? I don't know.

Comment: Based on the sentences you've provided, the lack of inversion is the problem, thus your corrected sentence with inversion is correct.

Comment: Based on the clip of the video that Em has kindly provided, I don't think there's any doubt about this being a matter of inversion, where the host (a Dutchman, Em thinks) simply got the grammar wrong by not being aware of  the inversion rule with "only".

Answer (score 2):

[1] **Only if we go out there and clean it up this amount of plastic is going to go down.*

[2] Only if we go out there and clean it up is this amount of plastic going to go down.

You heard right. [1] is wrong.

[2] has subject-auxiliary inversion. This occurs in declarative clauses only when certain types of element are put in front position. Negatives are one very obvious type of element that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion when fronted:

"Only" is not negative, but it is semantically close to a negative, in that "Only John liked it", for example, entails "No one other than John liked it".

Comment: FYI, I found a clip of the video, included in OP.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how the question is read.
`Only if we go out there and clean it up, this amount of plastic is going to go down.`

With the comma I added, the word "only" is equivalent to "but" or "however". That is, it's a counter point to something said in a previous sentence.

Without a comma, the meaning is equivalent to
`This amount of plastic is going to go down only if we go out there and clean it up.`
If that is the sense, then the original sentence should have an inversion.
`Only if we go out there and clean it up is this amount of plastic going to go down.`

So, is the sentence missing a comma, or missing an inversion?

<strike>A transcript in which the sentence appears shows it preceded by "Probably going to still be there in 100 years."  It also shows it **with** the comma that I added above, so it should have the comma, and not an inversion.</strike>

[CNN transcript](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1810/17/sn.01.html)

**It is clear from the intonation in the recently provided video that the speaker's intention was the "only if" construction, and he did miss the inversion.**

Comment: I found a clip of the video FWIW, included in OP. Apparently, the speaker is Dutch.